# Can I bind a variable on some condition?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I have a template:

```
(deftemplate drule
         (slot name1)
         (slot id)
         (multislot field1)
             (multislot value1)
         (slot name2)
         (multislot field2)
         (multislot value2))

(deftemplate claim
         (slot name)
         (multislot field)
         (multislot value))
```

Can I have rule which will

1. Check whether there are any claims with `name` same as the one in drule.
2. Check whether claim:field has value 'EmpName', if found then bind it to ?name.

Currently I have something as follows:

```
(defrule drule
    (drule (id ?id)
        (name1 ?name1)
        (name2 ?name2))
    (claim  (name ?name1)
        (field $?pf1 'EmpName' $?)
        (value $?pv1&:(= (length$ ?pf1) (length$ ?pv1)) ?name $?))
    (claim  (name ?name2)
        (field $?pf2 'EmpName' $?)
        (value $?pv2&:(= (length$ ?pf2) (length$ ?pv2)) ?name $?))
     ...
=>
    (assert (success ?name))
```

But it will bind only if all the selected claims have a field `EmpName`. I only want to check those claims with name
mentioned in drule. And if any of those claims have field 'EmpName' then it should be bound. If not just continue. My
rule fails if some `claims` do not have `EmpName` field at all. **Assumption** is that some claim will have `EmpName` field
and value.

Desired input and output:

```
(assert
   (claim (name 'Employee') 
          (field 'Company')
          (value 'ABC'))
   (claim (name 'Event')
          (field 'EmpName' 'EventName' 'Company')
          (value 'Bob' 'Conference' 'ABC'))
   (drule (id '001')
          (name1 'Employee')
          (field1 'Company')
          (value1 'ABC')
          (name2 'Event')
          (field2 'EventName')
          (value2 'Conference')))
```

Output:

```
(success 'Bob')
```

Sorry if it is very stupid, I tried using test$ and member$ on `field`. But could not figure it out. I am self-learning CLIPS in my free time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate drule
         (slot name1)
         (slot id)
         (multislot field1)
             (multislot value1)
         (slot name2)
         (multislot field2)
         (multislot value2))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate claim
         (slot name)
         (multislot field)
         (multislot value))
CLIPS>          
(defrule drule
   (drule (id ?id)
          (name1 ?name1)
          (name2 ?name2))
   (claim (name ?name1))
   (claim (name ?name2))
   (claim (name ?name1 | ?name2)
          (field $?pf1 'EmpName' $?)
          (value $?pv1&:(= (length$ ?pf1) (length$ ?pv1)) ?name $?))
   =>
   (assert (success ?name)))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   (claim (name 'Employee') 
          (field 'Company')
          (value 'ABC'))
   (claim (name 'Event')
          (field 'EmpName' 'EventName' 'Company')
          (value 'Bob' 'Conference' 'ABC'))
   (drule (id '001')
          (name1 'Employee')
          (field1 'Company')
          (value1 'ABC')
          (name2 'Event')
          (field2 'EventName')
          (value2 'Conference')))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      drule: f-3,f-1,f-2,f-2
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (claim (name 'Employee') (field 'Company') (value 'ABC'))
f-2     (claim (name 'Event') (field 'EmpName' 'EventName' 'Company') (value 'Bob' 'Conference' 'ABC'))
f-3     (drule (name1 'Employee') (id '001') (field1 'Company') (value1 'ABC') (name2 'Event') (field2 'EventName') (value2 'Conference'))
f-4     (success 'Bob')
For a total of 5 facts.
CLIPS>
```